# Has anyone every received a "Unhandled Expression Type: 1004" using Linq to NHibernate?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I have a linq query that is passed into NHibernate which Linq2NHibernate will parse and return me populated entities.

```
string firstName = "Ryan";
Store store = _repository.Query<Store>().Where(x => x.Employees.Select(y => y.FirstName).Contains(firstName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

The troublesome part is **x => x.Employees.Select(y => y.FirstName).Contains(firstName)**

What this should be doing is selecting Stores that have Employees with the name Ryan.

I receive an error on the line above stating "*Unhandled Expression Type: 1004*"

It appears to me that it is a limitation of Linq2NHibernate and the `.Select().Contains()` just can't be parsed.

Any ideas? Has anyone else every received this error? What can I do to fix it or work around it?

**[EDIT]**

Here is what I ended up using instead.

```
string firstName = "Ryan"
Store store = _repository.Query<Store>().Where(x => x.Employees.Any(y => y.FirstName == firstName)).FirstOrDefault();
```

The Linq query being `x => x.Employees.Any(y => y.FirstName == firstName)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use LINQ to NHibernate, but that's not how I'd write that query anywhere else. Try:

```
string firstName = "Ryan";
Store store = _repository.Query<Store>()
                         .Where(s => s.Employees.Any(
                                e => e.FirstName.Equals(
                                     firstName,  StringComparison.WhateverTypeYouNeed))
               ).FirstOrDefault();
```

If L2NH doesn't like string.Equals(), try ==

Comment: I pretty much used what you gave me with a few minor tweaks. Thanks.